# Use HTML class as Highcharts table data source

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using Highcharts for rendering some charts on a page. I am using an HTML table as it's data source and it's working like a charm.

Highcharts assumes that I am pointing to an ID for where it should look for that table, however I want it to look for a specific class instead.

Take the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/d15d0h2g/

```
data: {
    table: 'datatable'
}
```

The above is the selector, however I'd assume that I could swap that out with something like `$('#datatable')` or as I want `$('.foo')`. However none of these works.

So I don't know how this can be done, and Google dosen't seem to help much :)

I hope you guys can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others comming here with the same problem, regular selectors does not quite do it.

I had to do like so:

```
data: {
  table: document.querySelectorAll('.datatable')[0]
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ktqj69sc/1/

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as i know it does only support id selectors. You can try http://highcharttable.org/ instead.